# Debugging PXE booting problems with GRUB

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, efi, pxe

I want to boot the current Antergos Live CD via [pxe](/questions/tagged/pxe)[netboot](/questions/tagged/netboot).
To do this, I downloaded the ISO, mounted it and copied the contents into `/tftp/antergos/`.

Then I set up [dnsmasq](/questions/tagged/dnsmasq) to offer [tftp](/questions/tagged/tftp) and used

```
grub-mkstandalone -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/ -O x86_64-efi \
                  --fonts="unicode" -o bootx64.efi grub/grub.cfg
```

to generate an efi loader in `/tftp/antergos/arch/boot/` from the following `grub.cfg`:

```
set timeout=5

menuentry 'Antergos x86_64' {
     insmod net
     insmod tftp
     insmod efi_gop
     set net_default_server=192.168.0.1
     net_add_addr eno0 efinet0 192.168.0.150

        linux   (tftp)/antergos/arch/boot/vmlinuz archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ANTERGOS modules-load=loop rd.modules-load=loop udev.log-priority=crit rd.udev.log-priority=crit quiet splash
        initrd  (tftp)/antergos/arch/boot/archiso.img
}
```

[dnsmasq](/questions/tagged/dnsmasq) is configured to deliver `bootx64.efi`:

```
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/tftp
dhcp-option=option:Bootfile-name,"/antergos/arch/boot/bootx64.efi"
dhcp-boot=/antergos/arch/boot/bootx64.efi
dhcp-option-force=210,/antergos/
dhcp-option-force=66,192.168.0.1
dhcp-option=3,192.168.0.101
```

However, when I select [pxe](/questions/tagged/pxe) (IPv4) booting on my machine, it recieves the `bootx64.efi` and then goes straight to the [grub](/questions/tagged/grub) shell. In the shell I can `cat (memdisk)/grub/grub.cfg` and get the contents of above `grub.cfg` so I assume that the shell is coming from `bootx64.efi` and not from my existing local installation.

How do I diagnose what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that grub looks by default for `grub.cfg` in `(memdisk)/boot/grub`. The memdisk created by the command in the question (`grub-mkstandalone [...] -o bootx64.efi grub/grub.cfg`) looked like this:

```
- boot
- grub
 - grub.cfg
```

So grub would not find the `grub.cfg` and do nothing.

The solution was to call `grub-mkstandalone` from outside the `boot` folder and to pass it as part of the `grub.cfg` path like so:

```
grub-mkstandalone -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/   -O x86_64-efi  --fonts="unicode"  \
                  -o boot/bootx64.efi boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

which generates the following `(memdisk)` contents:

```
- boot
 - grub
  - grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer solves the problem by embedding configuration in `bootx64.efi` (aka `grub.efi`), but it's not the only way.

Check your DHCP server is setting the `next-server` option. For example with ISC DHCPd:

```
next-server 192.168.0.254;
```

grub uses this to know where to look for a config file as described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Network.html

If the client is downloading `grub.efi`, but not `grub.cfg`, the client boots to the `grub>` prompt and `$net_default_server` is empty, missing or incorrect next-server is likely the cause.

```
grub> echo $net_default_server
```

In my experience, `$prefix` will always be a `(memdisk)` path, whether or not `next-server` is set correctly and grub downloads a configuration file from the TFTP server:

```
grub> echo $prefix
(memdisk)/boot/grub
```